# Best strategy for pausing apt updates

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

I'm running a Postfix/Dovecot stack and I absolutely do not want unattended upgrades (tends to break things). However, I do want to update at some point. I'm thinking of adding packages to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. My concern is their dependencies updating, which may break them.

If I blacklist the main packages, their dependencies won't update right?

Comment: Sounds like a great plan for killing the whole system.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I presume your are using ubuntu.
You can mark the package on hold which will stop updates to these packages.

To hold back updates e.g. google-chrome

```
sudo apt-mark hold google-chrome-stable
```

To re-eanble updates use

```
sudo apt-mark unhold google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: And again, this will hold any dependencies related to that package?